Formdata issue in spring boot 3.2.4
I updated Spring boot from 3.1.0 to 3.2.4
After updating, request parameter for multipart(multipartparameternames) becoming empty.
Due to which RequestParam value becames null.
I am passing transactionId with File. And reading request as below in controller.
@RequestParam(value = "transactionId", required = false) UUID transactionId,
@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) final MultipartFile file

In spring boot 3.1.0, it was coming correct, but spring boot 3.2.4 it both the paparameters are empty.

Did you override the compiler plugin in maven?

I added these already
<properties>
 <java.version>17</java.version>
 <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
 <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
 <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <source>17</source>
  <target>17</target>
  <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
 </configuration>
</plugin>


Please don't add information like this as comments as that is totally unreadable. From what I can decipher is that you have added and overridden the plugin, remove it as well as the maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target properties.
